# Delphi 6 Project Size Limitation

Tags: delphi, delphi-6

Yes, this is a Delphi 6 question! Does anyone know if there are physical limitions to the size of the project the IDE can handle?  For example, the number of units used in the project?  I know for a fact that the debugger gives issues when your file goes bigger than 32k lines.  Recently we came to the conclusion that it looks like there is a limitation to the number of units included in the .dpr.

Our legacy app is round about 1.6m lines. We often get out of memory issues and RLINK issues.  Never exactly could we find the source of these issues.

Comment: For the IDE *out of memory* issue, I suggest you compile your application using the command line compiler and a make file. For the RLINK issues, I don't know since you didn't specified the issues.

Comment: And of course, you should probably update to the latest Delphi version. This may (or not) be a difficult task depending on what your application does with strings and which additional components and libraries your code is using. I successfully converted such large application written in Delphi 5 quite easily because the customer was only using components and libraries for which they had full source code.

Comment: A shot in the dark: it's not the number of units included, but the overall amount of code lines. Try to cut down one of your units drastically without changing what the project includes - it that changes behaviour you have your answer. As a long term approach: separate 1 project into several ones and compile them as DLLs which can then be loaded by your "main" project.

Comment: Before I retired I regularly built a D5 project which included 1.7 lines of my own code and as much again in 3rd party libraries without any out-of memory or linking problems.  Btw, if you are wanting to generate modules that can be loaded ar run-time, you may find it preferable to compile them as run-time packages (.BPL files) rather than DLLs - see [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/When_to_Use_Packages_and_DLLs).

Comment: @fpiette, the command line compiler does the same thing.  Some of the RLINK errors indicate an unsupported 16 resource, and that follows with an out of memory error. Unfortunately this project has plenty of third party stuff, and we're busy doing initial tests to convert everything to the latest delphi version, but until then, the issue with the stability continues on a day to day struggle.

Comment: @MartynA, that is great that you didn't have any issues.  We suspect third party tools that have an affect here too.  I've been wanting to try seperating some of the code into BPLs to see if that helps as well...

Comment: Delphi 6 is a 32-bit application built back when there was no realistic x64 OS (XP 64 was essentially an experiment) so it can only use up to 2GB RAM. There may not be any hard limit, the IDE is exhausting its available RAM. I doubt anyone thought 20 years ago what would happen if the 2GB RAM limit was reached.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i cant comment yet. So its an Answer.

We had Problems with Delphi 5. ~ 1.5 Million Lines of code with 3. Party.

As Mentioned by MartynA we created several

- Bpl Packages
- Shortened our Path Names for the Library and Search Path. (hit a length limit there)
- unloaded Components for day to day use. (we used a batch file to register deregister them? That was our solve to out of memory crashes. I think we fetched all Component Register und Deregister calls in a seperate Program)
- we did something to minimize the amount of compiled files. I think it was something like having the dcu from the BPL creation in a folder searched by the library path? that boosted compile time .. but with todays ssds .. i bet its unnecessary.

Conclusion:

- register and deregister Components for out of memory Issue.
- use Serach Path to limit the Files in the Project.

(watch out for NTFS Filesystem and the number of Files in a Folder ... theres a sweet spot afterwards the acces speed decreases (at least on Windows XP))